# my app doesn't load (on localhost:3000) - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have in the 1 controller (HomeController) and 1 file in the views (index), i dont no why when i get into localhost:3000/home/index this just loading and loading and in the terminal where i wrote rails s it doesn't saying nothing... maybe because the script in the controller? what i need to change to make the app works...?

this is the HomeController file:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  require 'open-uri'
  def index
    @query = gets.chomp
    agent = Mechanize.new
    page = agent.get("http://www.google.co.il/")
    search_form = page.form_with(:name => "f")
    search_form.field_with(:name => "q").value = @query.to_s
    search_results = agent.submit(search_form)
    site = (search_results/"a")[12].attributes['href']
    site = agent.get(site.to_s)
    @movie = (site/"object")
  end
end
```

this is the index.html.erb file (in the views):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
function show() {
    var movie = document.getElementById("m");
    movie.style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<%= form_tag( "#", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "חפש:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= link_to_function "חפש", "show()" %>
<% end %>

<div id="m" stlye="display:none;">
<% @movie %>
</div>
```

thanks very much for helping me...

Comment: Sounds like a problem with webrick as opposed to the application. Is webrick starting up properly? Are you able to access another controller / action?

Comment: yes webrick working properly other apps working for me

Comment: Why do you need open-uri? You don't need it for Mechanize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much to go on here, but I suspect your mechanize request is timing out. In general, it isn't a very good idea to do synchronous requests to an unreliable service (like the internet) during the request/response cycle. Have you tried your Mechanize lines in irb to see if they work?

Comment: How can the unreliableness can be fixed ?

Comment: How do you fix the unreliableness of the internet? Good question.

Comment: What I mean is how can the app deal with unreliableness of the Internet, not how to fix the unreliableness of the internet.